# SpiderOak - Is there a way to tell if my computer is "up to date" with the syncs?

Tags: cloud-storage

If I've made a change on one machine and the change has been "backed up" to the "SpiderOak cloud storage".  Is there any way I can tell if a 2nd machine is "up to date" (and has that change)?

If so, how can I do this?

Comment: This will depend entirely on the cloud storage provider that you are using and is not at all generic. You might want to rephrase this question to be a lot more specific.

Comment: SpiderOak is the cloud storage provider.  See so my question is specifically on how it works with SpiderOak.  It's FAQ for sync questions is [here, https://spideroak.com/faq/category/sync/](https://spideroak.com/faq/category/sync/), and at this time it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an *easy* way. In the view tab, you see your devices, and you can browse the files, their backup versions (by date). So in principle it appears you can verify a sync, although I'm not 100% sure the timestamps will be identical for synced files.